# Where can I find the sidebar with a list of crimes and punishments under Imperial Law?

Tags: warhammer-40k, content-identification, dark-heresy-1e

After seeing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251106/are-heretics-always-executed), asking about whether heretics are always executed when found within the Imperium of Mankind, I remembered reading a sidebar in the form of an in-universe document in one of the 40k RPG books that covered most of a page, and which detailed a list of offenses and their punishments under Imperial Law, most of which were punishable with execution. However, after I spent about an hour looking through all the books I could think of it possibly having been in, I couldn't find it.

If this sidebar exists and it's not my memory playing tricks on me, which book is it from, and what page is it on?

Comment: @WakiNadiVellir Yes, I remember it being in a book from the 40k RPG line, probably Dark Heresy 1e but possibly one of the other games in that line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Book of Judgement

You're probably remembering the spread covering pages 33 and 34 of the [*Book of Judgement*](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Dark_Heresy:_Book_of_Judgement) supplement for Dark Heresy. In setting, the Book of Judgement is the name of the Imperium's legal code, as enforced by the Arbites; accordingly, the supplement itself is all about Imperial law, the Adeptus Arbites and the criminal underworld of the Calixis sector.

The sidebar is presented as "A partial list of the most common crimes you will encounter during your Sibellus assignment", and does indeed call for execution as a consequence of most "crimes", e.g.:

> Unsanctioned Psychic Manifestation - Imprisonment to await transport
> Witness to Unsanctioned Psychic Manifestation -  Field Judgement (Execution)
> Survived Unsanctioned Psychic Manifestation - Field Judgement (Execution)
> Injured in Unsanctioned Psychic Manifestation - Field Judgement (Execution)

But hey, it's not all bad - if the Arbites can't *prove* you have intent to commit sedition and merely *suspect* that you do, they'll only execute your family up to one generation removed, rather than two!